# Get HTML body from a webpage in Android?

Tags: java, android, html

I want my Android app to check for update so I hosted a simple HTML page with this code:

```
<html>
<body>2.3</body>  // Latest version
</html>
```

So I would get the version in the Body and compare it to the current version that is in the phone.

How do I get that number from a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has left the net, io and nio.
Try the Java.net.URLConnection: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        URL url = new URL("http://url for your webpage");
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            builder.append(inputLine.trim());
        in.close();
        String htmlPage = builder.toString();
        String versionNumber = htmlPage.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

**NOTE:**  this will work only if your webpage contains html element like you put above  , but it doesnot work if there is an entity element like `&amp;` in your html page .